# PayPal Buy Now with Price Based on Form Field Value

Tags: javascript, wordpress, paypal

I am new to JavaScript and website design.  I created a pretty nice WordPress website using the Captain Form plugin for our bowling tournament.  I am now working on finalizing the registration form.  The form itself is done, but I am struggling with getting the payment process right.

One thing to note is that the form is set up so that users can submit the data for 1, 2, 3 or 4 bowlers and submit it.  Then, come back later and add the remaining bowlers.  The reason I am not using the Captain Form payment feature is that it does not allow bowlers to pay at different times.  So, if bowler 1 goes in and registers, then they send the link to bowler 2, 3 and 4...those bowlers have no way of accessing the payment function because the "submit" button is not being activated, only the update submission button.  Captain Form has told me this is something that cannot be changed.  Therefore, I am trying to utilize alternative methods to achieve my goal.

I have a field called "Total Amount Paying Today" that is a calculated field based on responses to other answers on the form.

My status/question:  How can I create a PayPal Pay Now button that takes the amount from the "Total Amount Paying Today" field and sends it and the user to PayPal to make their payment.

Here is a link to the registration form, I am open to all ideas, but please keep in mind I am very new to this, so please keep it simple for me!

https://texasrollofftournament.com/?post_type=captainform_post&p=388&cf_form_id=880216

Answer (score 0):

Try this link:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/customize-button/

Sample Integration:
https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/checkout

Here you can populate "amount" value with your "Total Amount Paying Today" field